# Pass IDs to Rails using Select2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select2-rails

This might be a dummy question. I have a multi-value field on a form with following Select2 settings

```
jQuery('#mymodel_thing_ids').select2
  multiple: true
  placeholder: "Select things"
  minimumResultsForSearch: -1
  ajax:
    url: "/things.json"
    dataType: "json"
    results: (data, page) ->
      results: data
  formatResult: (data) -> data.name
  formatSelection: (data) -> data.name
```

When submitting the form with selected *things* I'm getting

```
"thing_ids"=>"[],3,2"
```

i.e. initial value (empty square brackets) and IDs of selected *things*. But I'd like to have following

```
"thing_ids"=>"[3,2]"
```

Is it possible with Select2? And what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

To avoid braces in the beginning use *value=""* when creating an input element.

Comment: Try this `data.serialize()` . see here https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Select2 sends back a string list of items, e.g. `"thing_ids" => "1,2,3"`. What I do when using Select2 in this way is to create accessor methods for `thing_tokens` and `thing_tokens=`, which look something like this:

```
def thing_tokens
  thing_ids.join(",")
end

def thing_tokens=(token_string)
  self.thing_ids = token_string.split(",")
end
```

Then, in your form, you'll make it be an input for `:thing_tokens` instead of `thing_ids`. If you're using Rails 4, make sure you also permit `:thing_tokens` in your controller.

Comment: This answer does actually solve the problem by making the value a string and thus removing the `[]` from the value in the first place.

Comment: You can avoid those braces by setting input value to empty string, i.e. <input id="mymodel_thing_tokens" type="hidden" value="">